# How to find if part of search string exists in NSSet or NSArray in time better than O(n)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Lets say we have a set like this

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Box", @"Ball", @"Bat", nil];
```

and I have search string `Boxer`

```
NSString* searchString  = @"Boxer";
```

now once i search for `Boxer` in `NSSet` it should return a `true`, since a substring 'Box' exists which is prefix of "Boxer". Is this possible?

if the search string is "kickboxer" or "basketball" should return false.

If is so whats the best case. I know iterating and comparing would be possible with O(n) time is it possible to  better it?

Comment: Right need to return if portion of the prefix exists in the Set

Comment: is the size of NSSet

Answer (score 1):

you need to use predicate llike this:

```
NSMutableArray *cars = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Maruthi",@"Hyundai", @"Ford", @"Benz", @"BMW",@"Toyota",nil];

NSString *stringToSearch = @"i";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",stringToSearch]; // if you need case sensitive search avoid '[c]' in the predicate

NSArray *results = [cars filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, i am looking at matching prefix.
for example in your case if the search string was  "For" it should return true.
if your search for "i" (as you have mentioned) it should return false. Since none of the array contents have anything which starts with "i". Hope this clarifies things

Comment: Do like this : [yourString hasPrefix:@"searchPrefix"];

Comment: @Arcky what makes you think that this algorithm has a lower complexity class than `O(n)`? Whether n is the length of the string to be searched for, the length of the longest string in the array, or the length of the array, this still has to examine potentially every element and every character…

Comment: my bad i didnt read the other ans and comments earlier.Then, I guess brute force is the only soln here.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html  May be this can help

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant n is the size of the array

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the problem better. What substrings do you want to search for? Only substrings starting from the beginning? Is there a minimum length? So if your search string is "Boxer" you'd match "Box" but not "over"?

Or do you want to only search for the "stems" of words? If so then you'll need a dictionary API that lets you look up the stems of words.

If ANY substring will match then you have a much harder job. You'd have a LOT of different strings to match for. (B/o/x/e/r/Bo/Box/Boxe/Boxer/ox/oxe/oxer/xe/xer/er. And it gets worse for longer strings.)

@Arcky's predicate solution will let you search for substrings. Now you just need to identify all possible substrings that you want to match on, and issue a predicate for each one.

Comment: I am looking at matching only part of the prefix.

Comment: What part? Any string of characters starting from the beginning? Any limitations? You have to define your problem clearly before you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to retun true if a Substring of the search string is on the Set?
The right way should be use the NSPredicate as @Arcky say before. But that matches if the searchString is a substring of one of your set elements not the oposite.
For that you couldn't use predicates. You can allways do that by brute force:

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Box", @"Ball", @"Bat", nil];
NSString* searchString  = @"Boxer";
foreach(id obj in mySet){
   if ([searchString containsString:obj]) { //NOTE: Only works in iOS 8.0+
     return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thought about this is there a better way this takes O(n) time. Is there some other data)structure which i could use to optimize it to O(1) or atleast better than O(n).

Comment: You can allways build a tree with the letters of the elements of the set as nodes and iterate on it. something like:
`B - o - x
   - a - l - l
        - t`
and then compare char by char of your searchString.